# What is a good example to set a task that is due on specific event date?

Tags: gui-design, workflow, datepicker

I am working on a project for our CRM product, which the user required to have an ability to create task that's due certain days before and after a milestone date for a transaction (eg. closing dates for Real estate agent). Some of them would also request for making it repeating.

My question was how could i make the flow to set due time and recurrence a little easier on both mobile and web. Is there any great example for that?

This is my initial flow for it, but thinking it could be better.(calendar is just a place holder

[image: This is my initial flow for it, but thinking it could be better.(calendar is just a place holder)]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's best to start with a milestone as a starting point.

A workflow, might be the following:

1. Picking a milestone screen.
2. On the next screen, the date of selected milestone should be specified by a user.
3. Then, as shown in the first screen provided in the question, the due date picked. Perhaps, with a slight alteration that is described below.

The actual date should be displayed next to a picker component, thus a user may have an idea of a relation how the due date relates with the the one of milestone.

To implement that, a date chooser can be added, like the one presented below.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmvOaz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This date chooser should reflect the date resolved dynamically on any change done to due date picker presented in the screen one. Of course, such components relation should be established contrariwise as well.